# What is the maximum number of collections per SQL API database in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are considering partitioning our data through multiple collections, or creating a separate collection per key.
The key range is in tens of thousands, less than 100k. My concern here is the collections limit per each SQL (DocumentDB) database.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Azure Cosmos DB limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-cosmos-db-limits), it seems that there is no limit about the count of collection.

If you have any questions about the scale Azure Cosmos DB provides, you could send email to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com.

> Azure Cosmos DB is a global scale database in which throughput and storage can be scaled to handle whatever your application requires.

But I don't recommand that you create so huge number of collections, because collections are billing entities. For more information, you could refer to [Azure cosmos FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#what-is-a-collection).

> Collections are also the **billing entities** for Azure Cosmos DB. Each collection is billed hourly, based on the provisioned throughput and used storage space